# Understanding Intel ME (Management Engine) initialization

Tags: x86, intel, bios, firmware

Could someone please elaborate the initialization of IME present along the chipset? Is it initialized before processor coming out of reset? How's it handled in manufacturing mode?

Comment: The ME is resident in the PCH which is powered up by the Embedded controller (laptops) or the logic checking the PSU lines (desktops) or by the BMC (servers). When the PCH firmware is up and running it asserts the reset pins of the CPU allowing it to boot. So yes, the order is: EC/BMC/Logic -> PCH -> CPU. The PCH firmware uses the same flash as the BIOS and it is made by various modules, including the BUP (real initialisation of the PCH) and the ME. IDK what you mean by manufacturing mode, the initialisation sequence is mostly undocumented and quite long.

Comment: By Manufacturing I meant, the initial FW that will be loaded to ME(ME.bin). How will the ME have control to fetch it from BIOS flash?

Comment: The BIOS flash is attached to the PCH via an SPI bus (or LPC bus on old models). The ME runs on the PCH. It's always the PCH that reads the flash, even when acting on behalf of a CPU request. In the case of ME, there is no CPU request, just one from the processor insider the PCH.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Can we access Intel ME/PCH registers before processor comes out of reset? I think there are certain JTAG debuggers(ITP) which give control to these registers once processor is out of reset and ready to execute instructions.

Comment: I'm not sure. It's possible to implement a PCH that prevents access to its MMIO registers (or registers in any other interface) until the CPU ack the reset, I don't know if this is done. I think the PCH/ME and the CPU are two separate domain of execution and IIRC debugging the ME/PCH (once red unlocked) allow to boot, reset and power-off the CPU (thus not requiring it).

Comment: @MargaretBloom In power sequencing we see few signals from Board to PCH. Does it go directly to PCH or BMC? Would you please explain the role of power control unit(PCU)/PMU if BMC is already there to control entire system?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question, it's probably better to ask it as a separate question altogether. I've never investigated the role of BMC in-depth, the PMU is usually an in-chip unit that controls the chip itself (CPU or PCH or really anything) based on internal and *external* signals. AFAIK, the BMC is more general and may coordinated those external signals.

Comment: @MargaretBloom I will add a separate question on that. Thanks for the clear explanation. I had a last query to know. Who manages the sleep states among these entities (ME/BMC/PCH/PCU)?

Comment: The PCU manages the sleep states of its own device, both the CPU and the PCH have their own PCUs, IIRC. The software or the ME/BMC can request the CPU and/or the PCH to enter a specific sleep state. But the matter is a bit involved and one would need to look at the pinouts in the datasheet to get a better idea. I can't remember the whole picture out the top of my head unfortunately :(

Comment: @MargaretBloom Okay! Is there any communication happening between DDR and the processor/PCH before it's initialization? I believe in a typical x86 arch once the processor is out of reset, it loads the microcode(CAR stage), initializes UART and initializes DDR using MRC. Correct me if I am wrong.